# why does pointer in structure occur error in Visual C++ but GCC doesn't?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

We use a structure below.

```
struct  S
{
    int i;
    int *p;
};
```

Main process:

```
int main()
{
    S s;
    int *p = &s.i;
    p[0] = 4;
    p[1] = 3;
    printf("p[0]=%d\n", p[0]);
    printf("p[1]=%d\n", p[1]);
    s.p = p;
    s.p[0] = 1;
    s.p[1] = 2;

    printf("p[0]=%d\n", p[0]);
    printf("p[1]=%d\n", p[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Then our process run it occurred memory error in **s.p[1] = 1** when we compiled it with Visual C++.

But it can run when we compiled it with GCC.

Why does it occurred error in VC++ but GCC doesn't?

Comment: The only way to know is to read the assembly. In any case, almost anything could happen in that code, since it is writing a value *somewhere* to *something* and that thing doesn't exist.

Comment: It very well *could be* that `int` is 32-bits and `int*` is 64-bits in GCC which makes it pad the struct with 32-bits of padding after `i`, which would leave some area for `p[1]` to write into. *Maybe.*

Comment: undefined behaviour is undefined

Comment: @ZanLynx Thanks for your comment! I found that I used 64-bits GCC compiler. If I use 32-bits compiler, It will occur the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behaviour of `p[1] = 3;` is *undefined*.

`p` is *not* pointing to an array of at least two elements.

Answer (score 2):

With this statement:

```
int* p = &s.i;
```

you are initializing your pointer `p` with the address of **one** object, not an array. But with:

```
p[1] = 3;
```

and:

```
s.p[1] = 2;
```

you are trying to set the value of some second array element but there is no array to begin with. This causes [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

That being said your `p` inside the `main` has nothing to do with the `int* p` data member inside your class. It is also highly unlikely this works with GCC as `_tmain` is a Microsoft Visual C++ extension.

Comment: I'm sorry that I use _tmain in example code. Actually, I use main() to be compiled by GCC.